# Adding folder in eclipse in src directory without making it package

Tags: java, eclipse, packaging

While creating one folder in src directory in one project in eclipse, it makes that folder a package. Is there any way to avoid this folder from automatically being a package?
e.g., I add main folder in src directory. I don't want it to become a package. How can I do this?

Suppose I add folders in this manner: src/main/org/apache. I don't want main.org.apache to be a package, instead, I want the packaging to start from org. (i.e., org.apache).

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Eclipse forces you distinguish between source directories and ordinary folders.  Any subdirectories in a source folder will be considered a package.

In your case, you can create an ordinary folder outside of `src/` to prevent the subdirectories from being interpreted as packages.

Alternatively, you can modify the project properties to have `src/` be considered an ordinary directory, and put a source directory within it.

You can manage which directories in a project are considered source directories by:

1. Right-clicking your project, then click `Properties`.
2. In the left pane, click `Java Build Path`.  In the right pane, select the `Source tab`.
3. Here you can add/edit/remove source folders.

Comment: But if we do it this way and the files are no longer recognized as "src files", then how do we compile and run/debug the project (Ctrl F11)?

Comment: You're right, all of your code still needs to go into `src` folders or it won't be compiled.

Comment: Is there any way to config Eclipse such that we can put classes in a package into more than one folder?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to have multiple source directories -- is that right?  If so, you can turn an ordinary folder into a source folder by right-clicking the folder, click "Build Path", then click "Use as Source Folder".  I hope that helps!

Comment: Cool it works if there are non-clashing classes =) But do you have any idea how we can make it work for clashing classes as well? Which means two different files which contributes to the contents of a single class, something like a C# `partial` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: If it's outside the source folder, right-click the project -> Build Path -> Remove From Build Path.

Answer (score 12):

You need to go to Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source (tab).

Remove `src` from "Source Folders on Build Path"

Then *add* `src/main` as a source folder.  If you already have `org` under main, then your packages should start with `org` as desired.

Answer (score 5):

I added the "Excluded" pattern with value ** to 'Java Build Path -> Source - > src/main/resources' and my package became a simple folder in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a Java project in eclipse, the current working directory is the root folder of the project. So why not just create your resource folder there?

```
ProjectDirectory
../bin
../src
../resourceDirectory
```

Then, in your project, you can fetch `resourceDirectory` with

```
public File getDirectory(String dir) {
   File cwdir = new File(".").getParentFile(); // remove the "." in path
   for (File f : cwdir.listFiles()) {
      if (f.isDirectory() && f.getName().equals(dir)) {
          return f;
      }  
   }
   return null;
}
```

and

```
File resourceDir = getDirectory("resourceDirectory");
if (null == resourceDir) {
    System.err.println("Resource directory not found");
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

**Note :** you might perhaps want to create an utility class for the `getDirectory()` method, or something similar. This is just an example.

Bottom line is that the application will most likely be launched where it should be and you might just use a startup file (.bat, .sh, etc.) to do that anyway. There is no need of putting resource directories inside your source or binary folder; keep them separated.

Answer (score 0):

Any folder in src directory becomes a package. If you wish to have a main folder then create a source folder of name main and then create the required package in main folder.