# RobotFramework cannot import Java keyword library

Tags: java, python, eclipse, jython, robotframework

I did some robot framework python examples with pybot, and referenced .py files as my library files. The folder structure I used was test/lib/myLib.py and test/test/myTest.robot, where /test was at the same level as the /src folder in my project in eclipse.

I then tried to do similar things with a java project using jython. I have /test/test/myTest.robot which imports the library ../lib/myLib.java. I even tried importing this file using RIDE, but it always shows up as red text, meaning the import failed. The specific message I get from using jybot on the command line is:

```
"Importing test library 'C:\Users\cody\git\myProject\test\lib\myLib.java' failed: ImportError: No module named myLib"
```

I read that I might need to add it to classpath, and I think in order to do so, I need to make it a .jar file. I'd rather not do all that if possible to just leave it as a .java file. I attempted to add the lib folder to the build path... By that I mean I added the /test/lib folder to the "Source folders on build path". I also exported the darn thing as a jar and added that as a library. All this was done from the project properties in Eclipse.

I'm pretty stuck... any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Java being a compiled language, you need to compile your java Class before importing it with RobotFramework.

Normally, Eclipse would do that for you, and put the resulting `.class` files inside a `bin` repository. If not, you can issue the `javac path/to/file.java` command, and move the resulting `.class` file where you want it (somewhere referenced by the classpath.

From within the `.robot` file, you should have the line `Library   test/lib/myLib`, without neither `.java` nor `.class` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It sounds like I need to figure out why eclipse hasn't taken the file, compiled it, and put it in the bin directory or on the classpath. Is this because it is outside my /src directory in the project? Any idea how to get eclipse to do the work for me so that other users will have to do less manually stuff?

Comment: I am by no way an Eclipse expert, but I think you need to declare your `source` directories, in your project. Maybe you did not declare your `test` directory as a source, in your project's preferences? Like described [there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8025371/adding-folder-in-eclipse-in-src-directory-without-making-it-package)

Comment: Hmm, I believe I've already tried this, as I mentioned in my question, but I'll delve a little deeper into it a second time to see if it is in fact what I am looking for as a solution. I'll let you know.

Comment: Also, did you setup the option to build automatically (`project -> Build automatically`)? This should trigger the build on save.

Comment: yes, build automatically is checked. I've added the entire `/test` folder to the source directories and have verified that a `myLib.class` file is created and put into the `/bin` directory. I'm using absolute paths instead of relative paths now, when importing the library in the `.robot` file. When I just put the path to the file in the `/bin` directory without `.class`, I get a `file or directory does not exist` error. When I add `.class` to the filename path, I get `NoClassDefFoundError: myLib (wrong name: lib/myLib)`

Comment: Also, I recently found this addon from the other libraries section on robotframework.org: https://github.com/robotframework/JavalibCore/

I'm wondering if I need to have that installed first? If so, I'm not sure how to correctly install it into robot framework instead of my specific project.

Comment: I never used this add-on, so I don't think it is absolutely needed - maybe it is a part of RF, now?
Since the `.class` is in the `bin/` folder, could you launch robot framework with `java -cp "robotframework-2.8.7.jar;bin/;" org.robotframework.RobotFramework myTest.robot`, assuming that you have the standalone RF jar in your directory.

Comment: I haven't been using the jar, how should I implement it in my project correctly? I guess I need to add a robot framework project with the org.robot framework.robotframework package structure?

Comment: You can download the `.jar` from [Maven central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3Arobotframework), and put it in a `lib` folder in your project. Then, you call is as I described above, `java -cp "lib/robotframework-2.8.7.jar;bin/" org.robotframework.RobotFramework myTest.robot`

Comment: ok got this error: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.robotframework.RobotFramework`

Comment: This is strange. This line `java -cp robotframework-2.8.7.jar org.robotframework.RobotFramework` works perfectly for me, and displays the usage of Robot Framework. It does the same than this line `java -jar robotframework-2.8.7.jar`. Are you sure you are using the correct version of java (64/32) from your command line? Which OS are you using? You maybe have to replace the `/` by `\` for Windows, in my command lines.

Comment: Ok, I can use the jar now (dunno what I was doing wrong)... I can see that the `;bin/` part of the java statement adds everything in the bin folder to the classpath, but when running the command, I still get the `Importing test library myLib failed: NoClassDefFoundError: myLib (wrong name: myLib)`

Comment: so I fixed this by importing the library `lib.myLib`, since it was sitting in the `bin/lib/` folder after compiling. unfortunately, my project uses external libraries, and it uses one of those libraries during suite setup. I get an error, NoClassDefFoundError: <path>. the path to that resource is correct. I even tried adding that specific jar file after the `;bin/` part of your suggested command... I am starting to think robotframework will not be able to do what we want easily. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You're welcome. I think that the `bin/` only adds the files directly there, not recursively in the folders, so you would have to add `bin/;bin/lib/`, etc...